# alternate method for hash in perl

Tags: perl

There are 100 of records in the sql table, using hash with keys i am able to process all the records successfully and generated output.There might be a chance, the sql table may have millions of records.will all the values store in the hash.?? with out using hashes is there any other way to process all the records.

```
my %summaryhash;

my $Attrdaysql = qq{select PACKAGEID, STATUS, sum(NUMDAYSACTIVE)
                    from table
                    group by PACKAGEID,STATUS};

# Compile the statement.
my $Attrdays_Query = $DB->prepare($Attrdaysql) or niceExit(1,$DB->errstr);    

# Execute the statement.
$Attrdays_Query->execute() or niceExit(1,$DB->errstr);    

while( my ( $packageId,$status,$attrdays) = $Attrdays_Query->fetchrow_array() )
{
    my $sim;
    $summaryhash{ SIM } = $sim;
    $summaryhash{ $sim }{ $packageId }{ package_id } = $packageId;

    if ($status eq "ACTIVE")
    {           
        $summaryhash{ $sim }{ $packageId }{ activeDays } = $attrdays; 
    }
    elsif ($status eq "SUSPEND")
    {
        $summaryhash{ $sim }{ $packageId }{ suspendDays } = $attrdays;   
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is _why_ are you storing all records inside hash, and possible answer is to use query which will perform statistic calculations inside database.

Comment: Because i need to show all the "Active" and "Suspend" days based on the PackageID.

Comment: Why don't you organise your query fitting to the wanted result with 'order by' and instead of storing everything in memory, print/save/send them line-by-line?

Comment: Even i kept "Order by" PackageID and atlast im storing in hash only..is there any other way to drive with packageID while printing along with the active and suspend im also printing other values from the other table based on the packageID

Comment: I think the point we're trying to get at is: Databases are well optimised for handling data. You're probably better off doing this within the database than using perl to do fetch-and-process.

Answer (score 0):

> will all the values store in the hash?

Yes, as this test program shows it is fine to use hashes for millions of keys

```
time perl -e 'keys(%myhash)=13000000;for ('a'..'zzzzz') { $myhash{$_}++ }; print scalar keys %myhash;'
```